# How to partition with a sub summary in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am not an expert at SQL and am really struggling with this query (building in SQL Server Management Studio):

My data:

```
id_module     id_cr
---------------------
001           12345
001           67891
001           12345
001           25896
002           23456
003           78912
003           23456
004           34567
004           34567
004           34567
004           89123
004           34567
004           34567
004           89123
004           89123
004           66663
```

What I want it to look like - Show Top 2 pieces of content (by how many entries there are) per module:

```
Grouped by id_module    Grouped by id_cr         Count (sum) of id_cr
001                     12345                    2
001                     67891                    1

002                     23456                    1

003                     78912                    1
003                     23456                    1

004                     34567                    5
004                     89123                    3
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    id_module, id_cr,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id_module ORDER BY id_module) AS 'Ranking',
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_cr) AS webtrackerCount
FROM 
    webtracker_user 
WHERE
    id_module > 0 AND id_cr > 0 
ORDER BY 
    id_module, webtrackerCount DESC
```

This gives me all of the modules with each of the id_cr's listed on their own line instead of grouped.

Example:

```
id_module     id_cr        ranking    webtrackerCount
-----------------------------------------------------
001           64639        1          32
001           64639        1          32
(this is repeated 30 more times)
001           38099        1          12
(this is repeated 11 more times)
002           84562        1          50
(this is repeated 49 more times)
etc.
```

So, how far off am I?  Is there a way to do the report like I need?  Any help would be VERY much appreciated :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made some few modifications from the query you have given

QUERY 1

```
SELECT ID_MODULE, ID_CR
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_module,id_cr,
    Rank() OVER (Partition by id_module Order by id_module, id_cr ) AS 'Ranking',
    FROM webtracker_user ) a
WHERE a.Ranking <= 2
Order by ID_MODULE
```

i hope this works for you, let us know how's it going

---

Alternatively you can also make CTE to group the records, then make some rank, and then filter the prefered rank as follows

QUERY 2

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, Rank() OVER (Partition by id_module Order by  id_module, id_cr ) AS 'Ranking'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_module,id_cr
        FROM webtracker_user) a
)
SELECT ID_MODULE, ID_CR
FROM CTE a
WHERE a.Ranking <= 2
Order by ID_MODULE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  The first solution did not work for me - it brought back strange results.   The second solution worked GREAT!  So, I have one more question - how would I add the row for the total count of the id_cr to show - right now I can see id_module and id_cr but I would like to also see how many times those articles were hit... is that possible?

Comment: I figured it out...

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, Rank() OVER (Partition by id_module ORDER BY  id_module, id_cr ) AS 'Ranking'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_module,id_cr, count(id_cr) as totalcount
        FROM wt_user GROUP BY id_module, id_cr) a
)
SELECT id_module, id_cr, totalcount
FROM CTE a
WHERE a.Ranking <= 5 and id_module > 0 and id_cr > 0
ORDER BY id_module, totalcount DESC